# Angular- Wait until subscribes returns value

Tags: angular, async-await, promise, observable

In my app.component.ts, I have the code in constructor to fetch the json file and then parse it's data to a variable which is further passed to the message module.

This is my Jsonreadservice.ts.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'; 
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class JsonReadService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
    public getJSON(filepath): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.get(filepath);
    }
}
```

Further this is the code inside the constructor of my app.component.ts where the MsgModule takes the file data as the input in second argument.

```
 jsonFile:string;
 constructor( private jsonread: JsonReadService) {
 this.jsonread.getJSON(this.filepath).subscribe(data => { this.jsonFile=data;
          MsgHandler.MsgModule(ModuleName, this.jsonFile); });
 }
```

I need to wait to proceed with the execution until my message handler doesn't loads the contents from json file.

Comment: Please show the whole code. If this is inside an if-else, it'll be easier to reframe the whole observable to be returned conditionally instead of subscribing inside the if-block.

Comment: You can use nested subscriptions, or use async-await with your code , please share the whole code until we find a good solution

Comment: You seemed to have removed any mention of an if-else statement. As a general rule any statements that depend on the async data with observables must be inside the subscription.

Comment: I have kept that statement inside the subscription but what I want is that until my file loads in the MsgHandler, the code execution further should be suspended

Answer (score 0):

Move your function fom the constructor to on ngOninit().

In the angular livecycle the component constructor will be called before the application is mounted.

Comment: But i want to load this file before